# Google Search Console - Excluded by noindex tag

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt, yoast, sitemap.xml

I have a WordPress site with pages that Google Search Console (GSC) reports as "Excluded by ‘noindex’ tag"

The robots.txt file accessed by the Yoast plugin is as follows though:

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 2
```

Looking at the file url confirms this.

In the home page code I can see the robots meta tag as follows.

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow, max-image-preview:large, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1" />
```

And in WordPress's own settings:

Settings > Reading "Discourage search engines from indexing this site" is unchecked

I also have added the following sitemaps to GSC

```
/post_tag-sitemap.xml
/category-sitemap.xml
/attachment-sitemap.xml 
/page-sitemap.xml
/post-sitemap.xml
```

How can I get GSC to crawl and index them?

Cheers

Comment: Is your "home page" one of those affected? If not, then you should check what the meta tag contains on one of those that _is_ affected instead.

Comment: The "home page" is not affected, but I looked up one page and it does indeed block it - <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow"> - don't know why I didn't think of that :-)

On the page affected, in the Yoast Advanced drop down I have:
Allow search engines to show this Post in search results? - Yes (current default for all posts)
Should search engines follow links on this Post - Yes (radial button)
Meta robots advanced - blank
Canonical URL - blank

So where is it coming from???

Comment: OK, so there two pages. One is sitename/year/month/ & the other site name/page-title? The first is flagged as not indexed, the second is indexed.

Comment: So `/year/month/` is presumably an archive page then? Pretty sure those are deliberately set to `noindex, follow` - so that the links to the individual posts listed on there will get followed, but the archive page itself will not get indexed. You could look into changing that, if you want to - but IMHO that's a setup that makes sense to begin with.

Comment: Possibly, but I can't see them in my list of posts, only posts with titles. I don't have an archive plugin either. At least they do have noindex, nofollow otherwise I have duplicate content. I'm confused, hence I'm here :-) Thank you for your assistance btw CBroe

Comment: Here is one of the posts with the title as its name - https://www.britishpollingcouncil.org/polling-rules-and-uk-financial-markets/

Comment: And the 'duplicate' post with no index, nofollow - https://www.britishpollingcouncil.org/2018/10/

Comment: Yes, the latter simply are archive pages. They are not duplicates of single posts, it just looks like you only happen to have one post per month, for many of them - but https://www.britishpollingcouncil.org/2018/05/ for example has two.